# Error in file(description = xlsxFile) : invalid 'description' argument when using lapply

Tags: r

I used the below the below code to extract data from multiple excel worksheets in the same folder, from sheets with the name 'table'. This code was working for me a week ago,

```
library(readxl)
library(openxlsx)

path = "S:\\YJB\\Shared\\corpdata\\Community Division\\Team\\Divisional BAU\\21. Serious Incidents from June 2021\\Serious Incidents Notification Forms\\All_Data"
filenames <- dir(path, pattern ="*.xlsx")
filenames <- paste("S:\\YJB\\Shared\\corpdata\\Community Division\\Team\\Divisional BAU\\21. Serious Incidents from June 2021\\Serious Incidents Notification Forms\\All_Data\\", filenames, sep = "")

SheetList <- lapply("Table",openxlsx::read.xlsx,xlsxFile=filenames)
```

but now when run the line

```
SheetList <- lapply("Table",openxlsx::read.xlsx,xlsxFile=filenames)
```

I get the error message

```
Error in file(description = xlsxFile) : invalid 'description' argument
```

Can anyone advise me what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating on the wrong vector/list.

`read.xlsx` takes exactly one filename (and one table/sheet, incidentally), but (I'm inferring) your `filenames` object contains more than one file. I can reproduce this with:

```r
filenames <- list.files("~/Downloads/", pattern="xlsx$", full.names=TRUE)
length(filenames)
# [1] 2
openxlsx::read.xlsx(filenames)
# Error in file(description = xlsxFile) : invalid 'description' argument
lapply("Table", openxlsx::read.xlsx, xlsxFile = filenames)
# Error in file(description = xlsxFile) : invalid 'description' argument
```

Instead, since you are only retrieving one sheet from the files, iterate over `filenames`:

```r
alldata <- lapply(filenames, openxlsx::read.xlsx, sheet = "Table")
```

If there are multiple tables to be queries from all sheets, you'll need to iterate over both `filenames` and the vector of table names/indices. Two ways, producing two different structure.

1. List of lists of data,

   ```r
   alldata <- lapply(filenames, function(fn) lapply(tablenames, openxlsx::read.xslx, xlsxFile = fn))
   ```
2. Single list, though it's a little less obvious how to index a specific file's table *by name*.

   ```r
   eg <- expand.grid(filename = filenames, tablename = c("Table1", "Table2"))
   eg
   #                               filename tablename
   # 1 c:/Users/r2/Downloads/workbook1.xlsx    Table1
   # 2 c:/Users/r2/Downloads/workbook2.xlsx    Table1
   # 3 c:/Users/r2/Downloads/workbook1.xlsx    Table2
   # 4 c:/Users/r2/Downloads/workbook2.xlsx    Table2
   alldata <- Map(openxlsx::read.xlsx, eg$filename, eg$tablename)
   ```

Note:

- `list.files` and `dir`'s argument `pattern=` is a *regular expression*, so your `pattern="*.xlsx"` is working but you should not rely on "glob"-like patterns. Instead, use `pattern="\\.xlsx$"` or just `pattern="xlsx$"`;
- instead of `paste`ing the directory name to the filenames, just use `dir(..., full.names=TRUE)` on the original call. If you need at some point to have the actual filename component separate, there are two other functions `basename` (extracts the filename or top-level directory from a path) and `dirname` (extracts all exact the `basename` component).

Comment: Thanks for your response, it works perfecttly now